# What does it even mean to make an image visible to a writes (or available to reads)?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

An availability operation can be compared to a cache flush - cache contents are released to main memory.
Similarly, visibility operation can be compared to a cache invalidation - cache consumes contents of main memory.

*(it doesn't have to be a 1:1 hw mapping, but you get the idea)*

It seems nonsensical to perform a visibility operation before a write (since we're about to override whatever is in our imaginary or no-so-imaginary cache either way) or an availability operation after a read (nothing has changed!).

I saw code, which includes memory writes in dstAccessMask and/or memory reads in srcAccessMask. What's the point?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems nonsensical to perform a visibility operation before a write (since we're about to override whatever is in our imaginary or no-so-imaginary cache either way) or an availability operation after a read (nothing has changed!).

So *which* not-so-imaginary cache are you talking about? And how are you enforcing coherency with other not-so-imaginary caches in the system? GPUs have *many* levels of parallel caching, some of which are coherent in hardware and some of which are not. What you get is entirely implementation-defined behavior ...

> memory writes in dstAccessMask

Missing invalidation before a write can cause write-after-write hazards on the GPU (you can end up with mismatches in parallel copies of data in two different caches). Can also get issues if HOST modified the data, which is why HOST is a possible stage.

> memory reads in srcAccessMask

Can't think of a case where you'd need memory operations after a read-only usage.